# How to plot even function without noticeable asymmetry

Tags: numerics

I am trying to plot a series of functions. But the picture is looking a bit asymmetric despite that the functions are even.
If I try to use Geometricaltransformation function to reflect the plot that plot legend is getting reflected too and this is not required.
What can I do? I integrate, summ and put the option that function is even in the code.
[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

```
texStyle = {FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman", FontSize -> 20};
p0 = 1;(* pn1=5;p1=15;p2=40;p3=1000;*) g0 = 0.1; g1 = 1.5; g2 = 3.0; \
g3 = 5.0; eF = 500; B0 = 15; n0 = 
 Ceiling[eF/B0]; ni = 5; kFd = 3; T = 2;
g[B_, ga_] := ga*(1 + (2*B/ga/Sqrt[\[Pi]])^4)^(1/8);
igl[ga_, e_, n_, B_] := 
  g[B, ga]/((e - B*(n - 1/2))^2 + (g[B, ga])^2);
igg[ga_, e_, n_, B_] := 
  Sqrt[2*\[Pi]]*Exp[-2*(e - B*(n - 1/2))^2 /(g[B, ga])^2]/g[B, ga];
igd[ga_, e_, n_, B_] := 
  If[g[B, ga] > Abs[e - B*(n - 1/2)], (2/\[Pi])*
    Sqrt[(g[B, ga])^2 - (e - B*(n - 1/2))^2 ]/(g[B, ga])^2, 0];
n1[e_, \[Theta]_] := Ceiling[1.0*e/B0/Cos[\[Theta]]];
p1[\[Theta]_, g_] := 
  Ceiling[10*
    g*(1 + (2*B0*Cos[\[Theta]]/g/Sqrt[\[Pi]])^4)^(1/8)/B0/
     Cos[\[Theta]]];
n0t = Ceiling[eF/B0 + 1/2];
f0g[e_, \[Theta]_, g_] := 
  g*B0*Cos[\[Theta]]*
   Sum[(BesselJ[p, kFd*Tan[\[Theta]]])^2*
     igg[g, e, n, B0*Cos[\[Theta]]]*
     igg[g, e, n + p, B0*Cos[\[Theta]]], {n, 
     n1[e, \[Theta]] - p1[\[Theta], g], 
     n1[e, \[Theta]] + p1[\[Theta], g]}, {p, -p1[\[Theta], g], 
     p1[\[Theta], g]}];
f1g[\[Theta]_, g_] := 
  Sum[f0g[eF + 2*(i + 1/2)*T/ni, \[Theta], 
        g]/(Cosh[((i + 1/2)/ni)])^2, {i, -3*ni, 3*ni - 1}]/ni/24/T;
f0l[e_, \[Theta]_, g_] := 
  g*B0*Cos[\[Theta]]*
   Sum[(BesselJ[p, kFd*Tan[\[Theta]]])^2*
     igl[g, e, n, B0*Cos[\[Theta]]]*
     igl[g, e, n + p, B0*Cos[\[Theta]]], {n, 
     n1[e, \[Theta]] - p1[\[Theta], g], 
     n1[e, \[Theta]] + p1[\[Theta], g]}, {p, -p1[\[Theta], g], 
     p1[\[Theta], g]}];
f1l[\[Theta]_, g_] := 
  Sum[f0l[eF + 2*(i + 1/2)*T/ni, \[Theta], 
        g]/(Cosh[((i + 1/2)/ni)])^2, {i, -3*ni, 3*ni - 1}]/ni/24/T;
f0d[e_, \[Theta]_, g_] := 
  g*B0*Cos[\[Theta]]*
   Sum[(BesselJ[p, kFd*Tan[\[Theta]]])^2*
     igd[g, e, n, B0*Cos[\[Theta]]]*
     igd[g, e, n + p, B0*Cos[\[Theta]]], {n, 
     n1[e, \[Theta]] - p1[\[Theta], g], 
     n1[e, \[Theta]] + p1[\[Theta], g]}, {p, -p1[\[Theta], g], 
     p1[\[Theta], g]}];
f1d[\[Theta]_, g_] := 
  Sum[f0d[eF + 2*(i + 1/2)*T/ni, \[Theta], 
        g]/(Cosh[((i + 1/2)/ni)])^2, {i, -3*ni, 3*ni - 1}]/ni/24/T;
f1g0 = 1.0*f1g[0, g0];
f1l0 = 1.0*f1l[0, g0];
f1d0 = 1.0*f1d[0, g0];
f1gEv[x_, y_] := If[x >= 0, f1g[x, y], f1g[-x, y]];
f1lEv[x_, y_] := If[x >= 0, f1l[x, y], f1l[-x, y]];
f1dEv[x_, y_] := If[x >= 0, f1d[x, y], f1d[-x, y]];

pg = Plot[{f1lEv[\[Theta]*\[Pi]/180.0, g0]/f1l0, 
    f1gEv[\[Theta]*\[Pi]/180.0, g0]/f1g0, 
    f1dEv[\[Theta]*\[Pi]/180.0, g0]/f1d0}, {\[Theta], -85, 85}, 
   Frame -> True, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 16}, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    Placed[LineLegend[
      MaTeX[#, 
         Magnification -> 20/12] & @{"\\mathrm{Lorentzian\\ shape}", 
        "\\mathrm{Gaussian\\ shape}", 
        "\\mathrm{Self-consistent\\ Born\\ approximation}"}, 
      LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1}, LegendFunction -> Framed], {Center, 
      Top}], FrameLabel -> {MaTeX["\\theta,\\ ^\\circ", 
      Magnification -> 22/12], 
     MaTeX["\\sigma_{zz}/\\sigma^0_{zz}", Magnification -> 22/12]}, 
   PlotStyle -> {{Green}, {Thickness[0.006], Red, 
      Dashing[Large]}, {Thickness[0.004], Black, 
      Dashing[{0.0005, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02}]}}, 
   PerformanceGoal -> {"Speed"}, PlotPoints -> 600, 
   MaxRecursion -> 0, PlotRange -> {Full, {0, 1.6}}, 
   TicksStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 16], ImageSize -> 1000];
Show[pg]
```

Comment: Odd number of `PlotPoints`?

Comment: It made the plot more symmetric but not completely.

Comment: Hm. I see. I think there are two things going on: First, the dashing may cause slight assymetries. Second, there is quite some machine precision underflow happening due to `Cosh` and stuff. So, this is also a precision issue. Unfortunately, `Plot` will feed the function with machine precision numbers. You may try to precompute the function values in higher precision and then plot them with `ListLinePlot` instead, so that the rounding to machine precision takes place only in the end. Notice that you should to coerce all constants to exact number for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A symmetric `ParametricPlot` does the trick:

```
ParametricPlot[{{θ, f1lEv[θ*π/180.0, g0]/f1l0},
                {θ, f1gEv[θ*π/180.0, g0]/f1g0},
                {θ, f1dEv[θ*π/180.0, g0]/f1d0},
                {-θ, f1lEv[θ*π/180.0, g0]/f1l0},
                {-θ, f1gEv[θ*π/180.0, g0]/f1g0},
                {-θ, f1dEv[θ*π/180.0, g0]/f1d0}},
               {θ, 0, 85}, 
               Frame -> True,
               BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 16}, 
               PlotStyle -> {{Green},
                             {Thickness[0.006], Red, Dashing[Large]},
                             {Thickness[0.004], Black, Dashing[{0.0005, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02}]}},
               PerformanceGoal -> {"Speed"},
               PlotPoints -> 600,
               MaxRecursion -> 0, 
               PlotRange -> {Full, {0, 1.6}}, 
               TicksStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 16],
               ImageSize -> 1000, 
               AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image]

This requires setting the `AspectRatio` of the plot.

Remember that the list of `PlotStyle`s is used cyclically, so we only need to write down every style once.

Comment: I used the command to reflect the plot over axis but the plot legends is also reflected. If there is a way to reflect the plot without doubling of plot legends, please, tell me. Thanks. Show[pg, pg /. 
  L_Line :> {Red, 
    GeometricTransformation[L, ReflectionTransform[{-1, 0}]]}, 
 PlotRange -> All]

Comment: If you use my code and add your `PlotLegends` etc. it should work, no?

Comment: You code seems to be fine. Thanks. I am asking about ReflectionTransfrom and PlotLegends.

Comment: I think `GeometricTransformation ` and `ReflectionTransform` is not the right path here.